# Items inside scroll view are not showing up on mobile screen

Tags: android

I have a layout file as given below. I have one scroll view inside that one listview and one linear layout. When i install the app in mobile only listview is visible properly but all other layouts are invisible. I have two other textview which are not visible. How to solve this problem?

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             tools:context="com.example.app.Fragments.LFragment">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/l_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:divider="@null"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:animationCache="false"
                android:scrollingCache="false"
                android:smoothScrollbar="true">
            </ListView>


            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/assmt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="Assessment"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textSize="16sp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/assmt_name"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="sample"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textSize="16sp"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Parent View(ScrollView) have a separate scroll option and ListView have a separate scroll so when you try to use scroll listView that scroll option only working this case parent scroll not working.

Please try to use NestedScrollView.

NestedScrollView is just like ScrollView, but it supports acting as both a nested scrolling parent and child on both new and old versions of Android. Nested scrolling is enabled by default.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html

Example : https://inducesmile.com/android-tips/android-recyclerview-inside-nestedscrollview-example/

Answer (score 0):

Put the `ScrollView` as a parent like this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             tools:context="com.example.app.Fragments.LFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/l_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:divider="@null"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:animationCache="false"
                android:scrollingCache="false"
                android:smoothScrollbar="true">
            </ListView>


            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/assmt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="Assessment"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textSize="16sp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/assmt_name"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="sample"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textSize="16sp"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:layout_weight` property for views inside LinearLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/l_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".8"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:animationCache="false"
            android:scrollingCache="false"
            android:smoothScrollbar="true">
        </ListView>


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/assmt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="Assessment"
                    android:textSize="16sp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/assmt_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="sample"
                    android:textSize="16sp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I dont want lower card view layout to stick at one place